# Switching between .rdlc reports in reportViewer

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

I created 4 reports that contain information from 4 tables in a database. In my application I have a `menuStrip` that contains items that are named as this reports. How can I make my applications `reportViewer` display the report selected in the `menuStrip`?

I tried this code:

```
ReportDataSource RDS = new ReportDataSource();
RDS.Value = this.KontrolorKazneBindingSource;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Kontrolor\Kontrolor\KontrolorKazne.rdlc";
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

But I get an error: `A data source instance has not been suplied for the data source`

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I think you should call `reportViewer1.Reset()` to tell ReportViewer to create a new LocalReport instance for you. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.reset%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

After that you may give your ReportDataSource a name:

```
ReportDataSource RDS = new ReportDataSource("YourReportDataSourceName");
```

`YourReportDataSourceName` is the one you have set in report designer in the Report Data pane.

Comment: Yes I got it working in a similar way:
`ReportDataSource RDC = new ReportDataSource();
            RDC.Name = "KontrolorKazneIzvjestaj";
            RDC.Value = this.KontrolorKazneBindingSource;
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDC);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Kontrolor.KontrolorKazneIzvjestaj.rdlc";
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();`
I didn't need to call the reset method. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
        ReportViewer1.Reset();
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSouce = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource();

    if (DDAllRepotts.SelectedIndex == 1) {
        reportDataSouce.DataSourceId = "ObjectDataSourceALL"; 
        reportDataSouce.Name = "DataSetALL"; 
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSouce);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report7.rdlc";
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }

    else if (DDAllRepotts.SelectedIndex == 2) {
        reportDataSouce.DataSourceId = "ObjectDataSourceVoltage";
        reportDataSouce.Name = "DatasetForVoltage";
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSouce);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/ReportVoltage.rdlc";
        ObjectDataSourceVoltage.DataBind();
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
     }
```